# How do I add playback controls to my embedded swf?

Tags: flash, jing

So I've got my shiny new screencast created with Jing (which I love) and have put my swf file on my web server and embedded in a test html page.  It works just fine.  However, there are no playback controls on the video when I play it.  How can I added simple playback controls (pause, play, progress indicator minimally) to the video?

Here's the embed code I'm currently using:

```
<object width="1024" height="768">
    <param name="movie" value="swf/ClientSchedules1.swf">
    <embed src="swf/ClientSchedules1.swf" width="1024" height="768></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: I believe you will need access to the source for the swf file. This way you can add callbacks and execute flash functions on a javascript event

Answer (score 1):

Controls are images with functions, and have to be created with script commands to do anything. There are software applications that allow you to work through this. I have found with swf controls don't appear because you want them to. They are not embedded in the browser.